# Android Location Service - battery usage

Tags: android, performance, android-location

I'm developing an app which uses the location service from the start. My phone (Sony Z3 Compact) has a list of apps which used the location service in the location settings menu. It has each app with a "battery usage" message, like low battery usage, high battery usage etc. My app is listed as "High battery usage". Other apps which use location data like Tinder has it as "low battery usage".

I'd like to know what causes this and what's the best way to save battery. I see that each location provider has a "battery usage" data. Does that mean if I only use network provider as opposed to GPS provider I get the "low battery usage" stamp?

Or does it dependent on requesting location updates? Because I need the location only once, however I might want to check if the user has moved, for that I'd need to turn location updates on.

Any ideas regarding this?

Here is the service I'm using:

```
public class LocationTracker2 extends Service implements LocationListener {

    protected Context context;

    protected LocationManager locationManager;

    protected OnLocationChanged event;

    protected Location currentLocation;

    public interface OnLocationChanged {

        public void onLocationChanged(double latitude, double longitude);

    }

    public LocationTracker2(Context context, OnLocationChanged event) {
        this.context = context;
        this.event = event;
        locationManager = (LocationManager)context.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    }

    public boolean canGetLocation() {
        // getting GPS status
        boolean isGPSEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        // getting network status
        boolean isNetworkEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
        return (isGPSEnabled || isNetworkEnabled);
    }

    public void showSettingsAlert(){
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);

        // Setting Dialog Title
        alertDialog.setTitle("GPS is settings");

        // Setting Dialog Message
        alertDialog.setMessage("GPS is not enabled. Do you want to go to settings menu?");

        // On pressing Settings button
        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        // on pressing cancel button
        alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.cancel();
            }
        });

        // Showing Alert Message
        alertDialog.show();
    }

    public Location getCurrentLocation() {
        if(currentLocation != null) return currentLocation;
        List<String> providers = locationManager.getProviders(true);
        Location bestLocation = null;
        for (String provider : providers) {
            Location l = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
            if (l == null) {
                continue;
            }
            if (bestLocation == null || l.getAccuracy() < bestLocation.getAccuracy()) {
                // Found best last known location: %s", l);
                bestLocation = l;
            }
        }
        if(bestLocation != null) {
            currentLocation = bestLocation;
            this.event.onLocationChanged(currentLocation.getLatitude(), currentLocation.getLongitude());
        }
        return currentLocation;
    }

    public void startLocationUpdates() {
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        String bestProvider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(bestProvider, 60000, 10, this);
    }

    public void stopLocationUpdates() {
        locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        this.currentLocation = location;
        this.event.onLocationChanged(this.currentLocation.getLatitude(), this.currentLocation.getLongitude());
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When your app is using the GPS provider, it will be listed as High Usage app. The network provider will be listed as low usage.
If you will be using the GPS provider for only one point, you will be listed as High Usage, but for a short period.
I can suggest two alternatives for you:

1. First try to use the Passive Provider, if another app is using the location services at the moment you will receive their updates as well but the system will list them as the App who uses the battery.
2. Use the Google play location client, it will list the battery usage on Google Play Services instead of on you.